# Is it possible that tar-cvzf adds file information while zipping large file? (File is around 200 gb )

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, tar, unzip

I zipped a large regular unix file (.dat) using tar -cvzf command . This file is of around 200 gb in size.
After zipping it became 27gb in size. But while reading data in that zipped file i can see annonymous data added at start of file.
Is this possible?
I tried to unzip that file again and found that unzipped file has no such anonymous records.

Comment: Please explain what is an anonymous record for you.

Comment: I can see file  name , permissions  and few more bytes of data preceding with '\x00'

Comment: Yes, see header `tar.h`  mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yup. that helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) command is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Please study its source [code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/). Read of course its man page, [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Indeed, **a `tar` archive starts with a header** documented in header [file `tar.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.h?h=release_1_32). There is a [POSIX](http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/) standard related to [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)).

See also Peter Miller's [tardy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tardy/) utility.

**Don't confuse `tar` archives with [`zip` ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))** handled by [Info-ZIP](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/) (so `zip` and `unzip` commands).

[GNU zip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/) -a compressor, the `gzip` program which can be started by `tar`, notably your `tar czvf` command- is also free software, and of course you should study its source code if interested.

Some [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (notably [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/)) have a builtin `tar`.

> I tried to unzip that file again and found that unzipped file has no such anonymous records.

AFAIK, most Linux [filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) try to implement more or less the POSIX standard -based upon [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system calls, and they don't know about [records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)). If you need "records", consider using databases (like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)) or indexed files (like [GDBM](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)) - both built above Linux file systems or [block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV).

Read also a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Notice that "a large regular unix file" is mostly a sequence of bytes. **There is no notion of records** inside them, except as a *convention* used by other [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) programs thru [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html).

Comment: Thank you Basile for above info . I will go through tar.h file in my system to dig more into this.

Comment: Thank you Basile for this answer. I get all details abt  tar  process in wiki page that you shared in above answer. Thanks :)